What was the name of an old D&D module involving a clockwork mansion & two rival mages?
So there was a D&D module I remember.
Specifics:

The cover was a female mage who rides a feathered Dragon

The female mage is the rival of a male mage, and she has trapped him in his own clockwork creation

The male mage had a mansion with many clockwork
servants/warriors, but it's out of control since he's not around

The clockwork people were rated from 1-5, 5 being almost sentient

A level 5 clockwork (called Alex?) features heavily as he is trying to
save his master & he has a portable hole

This would have been late 80s or early 90s

The basement of the house is an automated clockwork factory, but it's producing clockworks with bits missing since the boss is out

The female mage does not feature heavily, but is a rival (but not enemy) of the male mage. She's magic'd him into a clockwork. If you save him he thinks it's a good trick by her

The male mage is shrunk and in a clockwork, you must solve a puzzle and if you fail a clockwork hammer guy smashes him.

The level 5 clockwork is programmed to hinder the player but is able to rebel against his programming to an extent (since he wants to save his master)



Clockwork Mage (WP entry)
Susan Stone & M.E. Allen

From PrinceofNOthingsBlog review:

A prankwar between Humbert the Clockwork Mage and the local magic user Kazin (who rides a feathered Red Dragon yyyeeessss) gets massively out of hand when Humbert actually steals her demon-controlling regalia and refuses to give them back for months on end, finally prompting her to shrink him and imprison him in a complex clockwork structure in the middle of his mansion. The adventurers are sent to investigate

I'll eat my hat (and buy both modules!) if it turns out there are two fitting this description from the period =D

Absolutely, this is it, leave that hat on your head friend.
